# Unit Testing for JS-Data

Tags: unit-testing, angular, store, jsdata

we are using JS-Data, JS-Data-Http to interact with Service in angular2 application. Having problem when we do the unit testing. Could anybody explain about how to create mock object for JS-Data-Http?

Comment: Please, provide details on how you use JS-Data in A2 app. Some code is necessary. I guess, the way to make it testable is to wrap A2's `Http` [in the same way it is done in A1 adapter](https://github.com/js-data/js-data-angular/blob/master/src/index.js#L60-L72). Due to the fact that `Http` uses observables and js-data-http expects promises, the wrapper should convert them to promises to mimic A1's `$http` API. By default js-data-http uses [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios), which is not very testable.

Comment: For unit testing on client side if you need a web service that provides your own data model as dummy data, you can use [Rest Ipsum](https://restipsum.com)

Answer (score 0):

Unit testing should not require external resources, like REST services. To mock a response for findAll, you would do something like the code below. Make sure you have included the JSData mocks, otherwise it will make an HTTP request and you will see errors due to unexpected request.

```
DS.expectFindAll('task')
  .respond([{"id": 1, "title": "Task 1"},{"id": 2, "title": "Task 2"}]);
```